Postgresql query with soft ordering
I have a table with around 100.000.000 entries mostly ordered by date of creation (without timezones and some entries <0.01% the primary key and the correct order would be identical).
One common use case is selecting the latest n entries by some arbitrary where statement which is slow.
One major bottleneck is maintaining the order,
sorting by:
date=>x1, id => x10, not at all => x100
Is there a way that would leverage the fact that my table is almost sorted?

To optimize queries for selecting the last n entries you can consider partitioning the table by date range. This allows PostgreSQL to only scan the relevant partitions which will be faster.
Update based on replies
There are some points to mention here:

First, it’s important to define what “slow” is in your context. For instance, are you considering queries taking more than X milliseconds as slow? Identifying this threshold will help in focusing on the most critical queries.

Then, you can get the slow queries by logging them along with their corresponding EXPLAIN plan. This will help you understand the execution path PostgreSQL is taking and where the bottlenecks might be.

For these queries, check what conditions are most used in the WHERE clause. This will help in defining an effective indexing strategy.

Based on the previous analysis, consider creating indexes that align with your query patterns. An index with id,date could work here.

Partitioning can help by creating smaller tables and indexes. This allows PostgreSQL to leverage partition pruning to only scan the relevant partitions, improving query performance.



I realized I chose the wrong word. I want the newest n rows, so the latest (not last). I'm unsure if partitioning will help here the where statement often selects entries randomly spread over the table so unless I can tell postgres to only look at the end it will have to sort all rows.

There’s already 100M rows in the table.  Has the partitioning ship already sailed?

Partitioning has unfortunately already sailed, the database is many years old. Currently I'm happy if I get it into single digit seconds range. The database schema was build for flexibility so we are in the range of 5 or 6 joins minimum, for looking up entries, 3 or 4 more for additional data
